# List.Distinct and List.Count Challenge

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Within PQ, I have a table of data (below) to which I am trying to determine whether all the columns titled Plan Status-# are the same, excluding blanks, and if all the same, display that value and if not display "Varies across plans"

[image: PQ Data]

The PQ code is below where I use List.Distinct to create a list of all "unique values".
I then use List.Count to count this number in the list and if 1, set the column equal to the Distinct value.

If List.Count({List.Distinct({[#"Plan Status-H"],[#"Plan Status-D"],[#"Plan Status-S"],[#"Plan Status-M"],[#"Plan Status-C"],[#"Plan Status-U"]})})=1 then List.Distinct({[#"Plan Status-H"],[#"Plan Status-D"],[#"Plan Status-S"],[#"Plan Status-M"],[#"Plan Status-C"],[#"Plan Status-U"]}) else "Varies across plans"

As per the table above, the List.Count does not seem to working correctly as some of the records show a merged value of items in the list which means the List.Count for a list with multiple values is calcing as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra brackets in your code. Try this:

```
if List.Count(List.Distinct({[#"Plan Status-H"],[#"Plan Status-D"],[#"Plan Status-S"],[#"Plan Status-M"],[#"Plan Status-C"],[#"Plan Status-U"]}))=1 
then List.Distinct({[#"Plan Status-H"],[#"Plan Status-D"],[#"Plan Status-S"],[#"Plan Status-M"],[#"Plan Status-C"],[#"Plan Status-U"]}) 
else "Varies across plans"
```

Comment: The removal of the extra brackets did reveal another challenge.  List.Distinct returns "blank" as a value so the minimum count is always 2 so it never triggers the first part of the if clause.  The question now is how to exclude "blank" as a valid value from List.Distinct.  I know there is the expression.condition option but never could find enough info on the net on how to use it.

Comment: Try List.NonNullCount https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-nonnullcount

Comment: When all was said and done:    if List.NonNullCount(List.Distinct({[#"Plan Status-H"],[#"Plan Status-D"],[#"Plan Status-S"],[#"Plan Status-M"],[#"Plan Status-C"],[#"Plan Status-U"]}))=1 
then List.First(List.Distinct(List.RemoveNulls({[#"Plan Status-H"],[#"Plan Status-D"],[#"Plan Status-S"],[#"Plan Status-M"],[#"Plan Status-C"],[#"Plan Status-U"]}))) 
else "Varies across plans")